# Using Python to Access Methods From C# Library - Interop .dll File

Tags: c#, python, .net, dll, python.net

I have a .dll file (with "Interop." prefix) containing a library written in C#. Within the library is a class, several enums, several interfaces, and several delgates. (Observed by decompiling the .dll with JetBrains dotPeek)

See the dll structure here:
[image: DllStructure]

I need to use pure Python to access the methods within the class. I have tried:

```
from ctypes import *
name = "Interop.HTBRAILLEDRIVERSERVERLib.dll"
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
```

However attempting to call any of the methods contained in the class "HtBrailleDriverClass" leads to "AttributeError: function 'initialize' not found". I have also attempted to access them from their ordinal indexes:

```
print mydll[1]
```

However this gives the error "AttributeError: function ordinal 1 not found".

Is anyone able to shed light on why I am unable to access the class within this .dll and why I cannot access any of the methods either?

Please bear in mind I must use pure Python.

Comment: did you try using Python for .NET (Python.NET)? ctypes cannot load .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python.net to access it

```
import clr,sys
sys.path.append("path of your dll")
clr.AddReference("YourDllName")
import YourDllName
```

Then Try printing any value of member of your class like

```
print YourDllName.ClassName.Member
```

from your python script

**Note : Your need to put clr.pyd and python.runtime.dll inside your**

**Python27/Dlls folder**

If You don't want to append your dll path then put the dll inside the python2.x/Lib/site-packages folder .
Then u can avoid 2nd line  - sys.path.append() too .

Comment: I tried this. I'm getting the following error: 
AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

Comment: Could you please paste the line of code which you tried , also Is import clr works on python shell. . ??